# Rails 4: Untraceable redirect results in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this extremely strange redirect occurring that I cannot trace in my console.  This is an example of when I see the error:

```
# this portion makes sense and processing should stop
Rendered recipe_searches/_recipes.html.erb (82.5ms)
  Rendered recipe_searches/show.js.erb (87.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 142ms (Views: 105.6ms | ActiveRecord: 7.9ms)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT

# Somehow I try to find a recipe with id 'thank-you' which does not exist
Started GET "/recipes/thank-you" for ::1 at 2017-07-27 14:19:25 -0400
Processing by RecipesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"thank-you"}
  ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" WHERE "sessions"."session_id" = $1  ORDER BY "sessions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["session_id", "a3279251fee30d7b6fcc9c48e671fc25"]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 528]]
  Recipe Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."slug" = $1  ORDER BY "recipes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["slug", "thank-you"]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
```

Here's an example of a time I do NOT see the error:

```
Rendered recipe_searches/_recipes.html.erb (89.0ms)
  Rendered recipe_searches/show.js.erb (94.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 157ms (Views: 112.7ms | ActiveRecord: 10.1ms)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
```

...and thats it.  I have no idea why my Recipe Controller's show action is being invoked at all.  Even stranger is that if I hit back from `/recipes/thank-you` and perform the same action I see the same error.  However, if I modify the url directly and change the url from `/recipes/thank-you` to `/recipes` and then perform the same action, there is no error.

Also, I see no request to "/recipes/thank-you" in my chrome dev tools.

It's also worth noting that the path `/thank-you` is reserved for when someone fills out a form from a different controller and the only way they get directed there is if certain session variables are present, all of which I've checked for, and they are not there.

**EDIT:  New info from comments**

I've narrowed down the issue to my ajax post request to the `recipe_searches#create` action.  When I post there, I get the redirect to "/recipes/thank-you" however If I make a standard post request, everything is fine.

Comment: What happens when you try that sql query directly?(The failure case).

Comment: It will fail because there is no `recipe` with slug `thank-you`.  The thing is there should not be any invocation of the show action on my recipe controller

Comment: I also don't see the request to "recipes/thank-you" in my network tab of my chrome dev tools

Comment: Can you post the controller action for `recipe_searches#show`? Also, I suppose there could be something in your `routes.rb`.

Comment: @JamesMilani so the way this works is that when you search for a recipe, the `RecipeController` calls `recipe_searches#create` and saves your search query, then redirects to `recipe_searches#show`.   

I actually removed the entire redirect to `recipe_searches#show` in an attempt to narrow things down and I was still redirected to `/recipes/thank-you`.  I think it's agnostic to the `RecipeSearchesController`

Comment: Well, I've narrowed it down a little.  I've removed the Ajax post to "/recipe_searches" (effectively disabling all searches) and the redirect does not occur

Comment: New Info:  I created a view with a normal form for creating recipe searches, which invokes the `recipe_searches#create` action that's been the cause of the issue, and there is no problem.  The problem only arises when the post is an Ajax post